# Refine javascript show/hide radio form options

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form which if you select yes or no via radio buttons it will give alternative options of either an image upload or a textarea to fill in.

My Js is a little bit wrong and not working...I am looking for advice as to where I have gone wrong...

```
<label>Can a Drawing be Supplied:</label><br>

Yes<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"> 
No<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">
<br>                
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none">               
  Image upload: <input type='file' id='yes' name='yes'><br>
</div>

<div id="ifNo" style="display:none">
  If no can you sepcify form and dimensions:<br>
<textarea type='text' id='other3' name='other3'></textarea><br>

function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
     document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
  } else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
}

function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('noCheck').checked) {
     document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
  } else document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate javascript functions. Put the if statements together in one of your "yesnoCheck" functions.

Comment: You actually don't need javascript for this.
`#yesCheck:checked ~ #ifYes {display: block;} #noCheck:checked ~ #ifNo {display: block};`

Comment: And it would be cleaner to supply the yesnoCheck function with a value `onchange="javascript:yesnoCheck('yes')"` and then act on that value instead of reading the checked (onchange will only run if the radiobutton is selected not deselected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Js you cannot have two functions with the same name. So, keep only one function, and threat the conditions inside it:

```
function yesnoCheck() {

    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {

        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {

        //Since it's a radio, if "yes" is not selected, the "no" is
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Also, the `onclick` event does not need the `javascript:` notation... It calls the function directly:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">
```

Comment: For some reason the no option isn't being hidden?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are interested in pure CSS solution. Remove inline styles, add the following css. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pzefdkv4/).

```
#ifYes, #ifNo { display: none;}
#yesCheck:checked ~ #ifYes {display: block;} 
#noCheck:checked ~ #ifNo {display: block;}
```

Works in modern browsers supporting `:checked` pseudo class and general sibling combinator `~`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('noCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For one thing your call to the function seems to be wrong:

```
 Yes<input type="radio" onclick="yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">
```

and then use jQuery:

```
 function yesnoCheck() {
   if ($("#yesCheck").is('checked')) {
       $("#ifYes").show();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why would he load a whole library just to make a quick check?